# Android AWS IoT example not updating shadow

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I have downloaded AWS IoT Android samples from [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples). I successfully run AndroidPubSub example given in above list. I can connect and subscribe. But message which I am publishing is not updating device shadow I have on AWS. Even when I update shadow on AWS console message not came on android device. I am missing something very small somewhere or am doing completely wrong?

Comment: I recently started to integrate the mobile SDK to my Android app, but my connection keeps on logging "Reconnecting" without throwing any exceptions. Do you have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you check internet connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was my mistake. Non of the document about android AWS IoT mentioned about it. While publishing message to topic we should mention complete topic string available in AWS console. i.e.

```
$aws/things/lamp/shadow/update
```

Now adding complete string as topic I am able to publish message to AWS IoT. To receive updates on android device subscribe to /update/accepted.

```
$aws/things/lamp/shadow/update/accepted
```

Comment: This is clearly mentioned in the AWS document. Your implementation must be designed by yourself. Sometimes we need "accepted" sometimes we use "delta". If ou understand the doc well you will understand what am I trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

@RamithDR

I was facing the same issue and then have added iot full access policy ,then it starts working.

AWSIoTFullAccess